# TestScheduler.RunTo does not update Now property

Tags: unit-testing, system.reactive

I am implementing a class `Cache` that depends on `IScheduler` and has property

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return scheduler.Now - lastUpdate < timeout; }
}
```

For testing I wanted to use `TestScheduler` but it's `RunTo` method does not behave the way I expect:

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
scheduler.RunTo(100);
scheduler.Ticks.Should().Be(100);  // Fails, actual value is 0
```

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wes [confirms on Rx MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/rx/thread/266c1ef3-4fb6-4af6-9fd8-5f9de714dd85) that it is a bug

Answer (score 4):

TestScheduler will run up until the last scheduled action, not all the way to the RunTo time.

So using the example:

```
var a = 1;
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
scheduler.Schedule(() => a++, TimeSpan.FromTicks(50));
scheduler.RunTo(100);
```

scheduler.Ticks will equal 50.

```
var a = 1;
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
scheduler.Schedule(() => a++, TimeSpan.FromTicks(50));
scheduler.Schedule(() => a++, TimeSpan.FromTicks(70));
scheduler.RunTo(100);
```

scheduler.Ticks will equal 70.

I assume this is to not waste cycles processing the clock all the way to the RunTo as there's nothing scheduled for it to execute.

Comment: I'd say that the amount of CPU cycles involved in advancing to RunTo time is negligible - one assignment operation.

Comment: @Konstantin Spirin - I agree. I was just taking a stab as to why it behaved as it does it. If it's a bug then that's cool with me. Sure it'll be sorted in the next release.